# CSharp Windows Form Picturebox Draw Small Image Without Quality Loss

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I'm trying to create a level editor using Windows Forms for my monogame project and need to draw small pixel based images to a picture box with no quality loss when scaled. In monogame when I need to do this I can just set the draw type to PointClamp and then each pixel is drawn as is instead of being pixelated when zoomed; I was hoping for something like this via  a picturebox. Right now it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiNOn.png) But I'd prefer a more crisp and clean image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00DDq.png) (The second is how it'll appear in monogame). I haven't uploaded any code for this, but just assume I grabbed an image from the filestream and used the bitmap constructor to scale it up (don't think that's relevent but I'll just put it out there).

```
Image croppedImage, image = tileMap.tileBox.Image;
var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

try { croppedImage = CropImage(image, tileMap.highlightedRect); } catch {
    return; // If crop target is outside bounds of image then return
}

float scale = Math.Min(higlightedTileBox.Width / croppedImage.Width, higlightedTileBox.Height / image.Height);

var scaleWidth = (int)(higlightedTileBox.Width * scale);
var scaleHeight = (int)(higlightedTileBox.Height * scale);

try { higlightedTileBox.Image = new Bitmap(croppedImage, new Size(scaleWidth, scaleHeight)); } catch {
    return; // Image couldn't be scaled or highlighted tileBox couldn't be set to desired image
}
```

CropImage:

```
private static Image CropImage(Bitmap img, Rectangle cropArea) {
    return img.Clone(cropArea, img.PixelFormat);
}

private static Image CropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea) {
    return CropImage(new Bitmap(img), cropArea);
}
```

The code above is my current method in it's entirety. tileMap is a form and tilebox is the picturebox within that form.image is the full spritesheet texture before being cropped to what the user has highlighted. After being cropped I attempt to set the current picturebox (highlightedTileBox's) image to a scaled up version of the cropped image.

Comment: we need more code!

Comment: Okay, gimme a sec

Comment: @leAthlon I've added some more code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got a solution by trying around a bit.
It looks like scaling images directly by size is using some sort of interpolation.
To try different interpolation modes supported by Winforms, I created a little demo.
As you can see, every label contains the name of the InterpolationMode and is followed by its resulting image. The original bitmap I used is the small one at the top.
[image]
From your question, it looks like you would like to achieve something like NearestNeighbour.

Following code scales bmp and the result is stored in bmp2. Try if that's what you want. Consider building a proper implementation if you're using this as solution (disposing unused bitmaps etc.). 
I hope it helps.

```
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("test.bmp");
        Bitmap bmp2;
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp2=new Bitmap(bmp.Width * 2, bmp.Height * 2));
        g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        g.DrawImage(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.Width * 2, bmp.Height * 2);
        g.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thnx I'll try this out. Just spent an hour trying to create a XNA control for my form but this seems easier so I'll just delete that.

Comment: if it is what you wanted, consider accepting the answer.